# aggregates in jpa criteria api

Tags: hibernate, jpa, aggregate, criteria-api

How can I do queries such as this using jpa criteria api:

```
select a.c1, sum(b.c1) from a join b on a.c0 = b.c0 ....
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
public static Specification<OrderEntity> x(String orderId) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {

        Root<OrderItemEntity> itemRoot = query.from(OrderItemEntity.class);

        query.multiselect(root.get(OrderEntity_.orderNo), cb.sum(itemRoot.get(OrderItemEntity_.quantity)));

        return cb.equal(root.get(OrderEntity_.orderNo), orderId);
    };
}
```

OrderEntity is the first table and the OrderItemEntity is the second table. I want to retrieve some columns from OrderEntity table and some aggregates on columns from OrderItemEntity table. The above specification results in a query that looks like this:

```
select order.orderNo from order join order_item on ...
```

So the OrderItemEntity table is joined but the aggregate columns are not included in the query.

Comment: Spring has no "Criteria API". The JPA API has a Criteria API. post title fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try by creating a join and accessing column from it:

```
Join<OrderEntity, OrderItemEntity> itemJoin = root.join(OrderEntity_.your_join_column);

query.multiselect(root.get(OrderEntity_.orderNo), cb.sum(itemJoin.get(OrderItemEntity_.quantity)));

return cb.equal(root.get(OrderEntity_.orderNo), orderId);
```